# Overwraping lines when using ssh by osx terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh, terminal

I'm using `ssh` command from osx terminal to connect my centos remote server.
If I type long string and want to go next line, the characters don't go to second line but come back the first line left side. And they overwrap prompt strings.

For example, I want to type like this.

> [username@hostname ~] loooooooooooong command and the arguments that come
>
> to second line

But it ends up like this.

> to second linename ~] loooooooooooong command and the arguments that come

Is there way to avoid this over-wrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usually happens if the prompt contains non-printing characters that are not surrounded with `\[` and `\]`.

So for example use `PS1='\[\e[33;1m\]\W\[\e[m\] '` instead of `PS1='\e[33;1m\W\e[m '`.

Comment: Thanks! I was used like `GREEN="0;32"
START_COLOR="\e[${GREEN}m"
END_COLOR="\e[0m"
PS1="${START_COLOR}\[\u@SakuraVPS \W$\]${END_COLOR}\]"

Comment: I rewrite is like `GREEN="0;32"
START_COLOR="\e[${GREEN}m"
END_COLOR="\e[0m"
PS1="\[${START_COLOR}\u@SakuraVPS \W$ ${END_COLOR}\]"`, then over-wrapping is solved. But another problem happens, when I hit a character and delete the charactor, then the prompt strings also deleted. why is that happens?

Answer (score 0):

I have this happen occasionally and the `reset` command (run on the remote host) usually brings back wrapped lines for me.